# R Difference between consecutive rows while retaining first row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a solution (`dplyr` preferred) that will allow to retain / copy original value of first row, while computing the difference (lag) between consecutive rows.

The data I'm working with is cumulative time of response (`time`). First row for each `id` need to be retained.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                     time = c(26204, 46692, 60268, 86240, 91872, 291242, 312311, 
                              333983, 355122, 364841)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                            -10L))

df
   id   time
1   1  26204
2   1  46692
3   1  60268
4   1  86240
5   1  91872
6   2 291242
7   2 312311
8   2 333983
9   2 355122
10  2 364841
```

When using the `lag` function from `dplyr` I'm able to compute difference scores (`rt`) while keeping fist value at `NA` or `O`

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(rt = time - lag(time))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
      id   time    rt
   <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  26204    NA
 2     1  46692 20488
 3     1  60268 13576
 4     1  86240 25972
 5     1  91872  5632
 6     2 291242    NA
 7     2 312311 21069
 8     2 333983 21672
 9     2 355122 21139
10     2 364841  9719
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(rt = time - lag(time, default = first(time)))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
      id   time    rt
   <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  26204     0
 2     1  46692 20488
 3     1  60268 13576
 4     1  86240 25972
 5     1  91872  5632
 6     2 291242     0
 7     2 312311 21069
 8     2 333983 21672
 9     2 355122 21139
10     2 364841  9719
```

What should I do, to replace the `NA`s with whatever is the corresponding value in my original column?

Is there a more elegant way that will allow to handle it within a single statement rather then using:

```
df$rt[is.na(df$rt)] <- df$time[is.na(df$rt)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should use `default = 0`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(rt = time - lag(time, default = 0))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
      id   time     rt
   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1  26204  26204
 2     1  46692  20488
 3     1  60268  13576
 4     1  86240  25972
 5     1  91872   5632
 6     2 291242 291242
 7     2 312311  21069
 8     2 333983  21672
 9     2 355122  21139
10     2 364841   9719
```